# Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership including "managed by"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

i have a skript to check a users groups but what would be nice to have is the owner of the group ("managed by") as well.

```
$Username = Read-Host "Enter User ID"
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$name = Get-ADUser "$Username" | select name

write-output "Status: $date $Username $name"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Username | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description  | export-csv C:\temp\$date-$Username-$name.csv
ii C:\temp\
```

Very appreciated for any kind of help.

:-)

Comment: you are getting all the props for each group ... and then throwing away all but two. so ... why don't you just keep the additional one you want?

Answer (score 1):

As [Lee_Dailey commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831988/get-adprincipalgroupmembership-including-managed-by#comment125219912_70831988) it is a waste to ask for **all** properties when you only want a few..

Also, you should always test if the user entered in the Read-Host can be found at all, because anyone can type just about anything there.

Try

```
$Username = Read-Host "Enter User ID"

# try and find the user in AD
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($user) {
    # Get-ADGroup already returns these properties by default:
    # DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, GroupScope, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID
    # so only ask for the extra properties you need
    $user | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Get-ADGroup -Properties Description, ManagedBy | ForEach-Object {
        # try and get the group manager from the DistinguishedName in the ManagedBy property
        $manager = if ($_.managedBy) { (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.managedBy).Name } else { 'Not set' }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name        = $_.Name
            Description = $_.Description
            ManagedBy   = $manager
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path 'C:\Temp' -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}-{1}.csv' -f (Get-Date), $user.Name )) -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User '$Username' not found.."
}
```